# import package error in java and class name ambiguity

Tags: java, import, package

I am learning packages in java but i am facing some errors.

i have three java files...

First: ClassAA.java-

```
package Mypack;
public class ClassAA{
public ClassAA()
{
    System.out.println("class A's constructor is called.");
}
public void testA()
{
    System.out.println("class A's methos is called");
}
}
```

second: ClassBB.java-

```
package Mypack;
public class ClassBB{
public ClassBB()
{
    System.out.println("class B's constructor is called.");
}
public void testB()
{
    System.out.println("class B's methos is called");
}
}
```

And third one is main class PackageDemo.java-

```
import Mypack.*;
class PackageDemo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ClassAA a1 = new ClassAA();
    a1.testA();
    ClassBB b1 = new ClassBB();
    b1.testB();
}
}
```

now i want to import Mypack package using import Mypack.* in main class, but is is showing error -

```
PackageDemo.java:6: error: cannot access ClassAA
            ClassAA a1 = new ClassAA();
            ^
bad source file: .\ClassAA.java
file does not contain class ClassAA
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
1 error
```

i found two solution to this problem.

first one-

put ClassAA.java and ClassBB.java files in Mypack package. if i do so it is working, but i do not think java forces us to do so (i am not sure).

Second one(i found this solution on stackoverflow)-

Rename ClassAA.java and ClassBB.java files because java compiler getting confused with name. (that is why it is giving error bad file etc.)
but if i rename these two files it is showing me another error.

```
 error: class ClassAA is public, should be declared in a file named ClassAA.java
public class ClassAA{
   ^
1 error
```

so now what should i do please help me. i want to import package using import.* .

Comment: As you can see, your second solution is not a solution at all. The directory tree must match the package tree. It's as simple as that. Note that the naming convention for packagesis all-lowercase. So it should be `mypack`, not `Mypack`.

Comment: So what changes i should make to make this program error free. it is working with other case but problem is with when i import package with Mypack .* ; the program is working with import Mypack.ClassAA ;

Comment: Again, the package tree needs to match the directory tree. So the class `mypack.ClassAA` must be in the file mypack/ClassAA.java. And the class `mypack.ClassBB` must be in the file mypack/ClassBB.java